# Is the Stokes operator positive-definite? (I don't understand the argument of the authors in a book that I'm reading)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

I'm reading *Navier-Stokes Equations and Turbulence*. [The authors define](https://books.google.de/books?id=f4zaccq9KREC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%22It+is+useful+to+distinguish+the+term+related+to+the+enstrophy+in+the+inner+product+and%22&source=bl&ots=Zbrk9PaLHh&sig=ULCgubhAYqVpbgrCKpcIKqzSHZo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy6f_58qXOAhVDshQKHUK9C8AQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22It%20is%20useful%20to%20distinguish%20the%20term%20related%20to%20the%20enstrophy%20in%20the%20inner%20product%20and%22&f=false) $$\left\|u\right\|^2:=\left\|\nabla u\right\|_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for }u\in H^1(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)$$ and [state that the Stokes operator $A$ is positive-define](https://books.google.de/books?id=f4zaccq9KREC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22which+follows+from+integration+by+parts%22+%22is+a+positive+definite+operator%22&source=bl&ots=Zbrk9PaJIo&sig=u1LQqLGhcXmy7Rc15vboWHnaAeU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi62c-i8qXOAhXLwBQKHc-0AGwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22which%20follows%20from%20integration%20by%20parts%22%20%22is%20a%20positive%20definite%20operator%22&f=false), because $$\langle u,Au\rangle_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\left\|u\right\|\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in D(A)\color{blue}{\subseteq H^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\;.\tag 1$$ I don't understand this. Shouldn't $(1)$ only imply that $A$ is positive-semidefinite? There are obviously elements $0\ne u\in H^1(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)$ with $\nabla u=0$.

Comment: Is there some kind of boundary condition on $u\in D(A)$ (e.g. $u = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$)? If so, then $\nabla u = 0\implies u=0$.

Comment: @JoeyZou $D(A)$ is a subset of $H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ too. I know nothing about the trace operator, but I've read that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$ iff $\left.u\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0$. Is that what you mean? And do you have a reference for the proof of your $\nabla u=0\Rightarrow u=0$?